# how to pull code review reports from TFSGIT

Tags: tfs, pull-request, tfs-code-review

I am trying to pull code review reports from the TFSGIT/VSTS, but I don't see anything out of the box.
The 3rd part code review tools like "ReviewAssistant" works great but they are not integrated with the Pull Request. It decouples code review to pull request.
I would like to get reports from the PullRequest code comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull data from TFS with [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1).

To get the PR code comments you can use the [Pull Request Threads - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20threads/list?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1).

The request is:

```
https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/threads?api-version=4.1
```

In the JSON response, you will get the comments and the comment location in the code (line number):

```
"comments": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "parentCommentId": 0,
    "author": {
    "displayName": "Shayki Abramczyk",
    "url": "https://spsprodweu3.vssps.visualstudio.com/Ac256a93d-7cea-4070-xxxxxxxxx/_apis/Identities/7a9a9b44-a2f1-6dfd-a7f6-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "_links": {
        "avatar": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxx/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/msa.N2E5YTlxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "id": "7a9a9b44-a2f1-6dfd-a7f6-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "uniqueName": "xxxxxxxx",
    "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=7a9a9b44-a2f1-6dfd-a7f6-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "descriptor": "msa.N2E5YTliNDQtYTJmMS03ZGZkLWE3Zjxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "content": "test comment",
    "publishedDate": "2019-02-25T11:11:03.45Z",
    "lastUpdatedDate": "2019-02-25T11:11:03.45Z",
    "lastContentUpdatedDate": "2019-02-25T11:11:03.45Z",
    "commentType": "text",
    "usersLiked": [

    ]
}
],
"status": "active",
"threadContext": {
"filePath": "/SampleForVSTS/Program.cs",
"leftFileStart": {
    "line": 14,
    "offset": 1
},
"leftFileEnd": {
    "line": 14,
    "offset": 10
}
},
```

As you can see there is a comment `test comment` at line `14` in the file `SampleForVSTS/Program.cs`.

You can write simple code in any language to get the data with Rest API.

Comment: Is there an API to get comments for developer/reviewer?

Comment: What do you mean? is not what I answered?

Comment: It says {pullRequestId} as one of the parameters. I want 2 reports. 1.all comments received by the developer including all pull requests. 2. All comments given by reviewer for all pull requests.

Comment: Try to play with the API of Get Pull Requests, then iterate them and get the comments.